# Remove database name from mongodb list of databases

Tags: mongodb, database

When dropping a database from mongodb, the database contents are dropped, but the database name continues to clutter the database list:

```
$ mongo localhost:49996
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.7
connecting to: localhost:49996/test
> use mp_scratch
switched to db mp_scratch
> db.dropDatabase()
{ "dropped" : "mp_scratch", "ok" : 1 }
> show dbs
mp_scratch  (empty)
test    (empty)
```

Is there any way to remove mp_scratch from the db list? I've been all over SO, the mongo docs, and google, but haven't been able to find anything, which naively seems crazy. On the other hand, is there a reason that removing the database completely is impossible?

Comment: maybe you should upgrade from 2.0 - we're on 2.4 now.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Server (v 2.0.0 btw) or client or both? The server is remote and I have no control over it, unfortunately - localhost:49996 is a ssh tunnel.

Comment: your client is 2.0.7 - you can check the server version with db.version() - if the server is on a later version than you are, I would recommend upgrading your client version at least to match. Upgrading just the client won't help with this (empty) issue but it's got nothing to do with permissions on files.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky the server is 2.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

I am using MongoDb for Windows 7, version 2.4.2 and the database was correctly removed.

But it's possible delete the files from data directory in the variable "dbpath". That can be found at the second line of "mongod"'s process log.

The files from this db starts with the same name of your database.

The reason for this problem, probably is because the user who runs the process do not have all  the permissions to manipulate the disk files.

Comment: no, this has nothing to do with file permissions - it's best not to mess with the files inside of /data/db in any case.